# C# - How do I Pass a delegate into another method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, methods, void

I'm writing a class for managing my threading. How do I pass my method that needs threading into my helper class?

All that I'll be doing is creating a new thread and passing the method I've passed through into a new ThreadStart().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't passing a void, you're passing a delegate.  The definition of the ThreadStart delegate is: public delegate void ThreadStart();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than write your own class to manage threading I suggest you check out the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class in .NET 2.0 onwards.

Comment: Actually, this might be the best way forward, I don't know what I was thinking!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by passing `void` but this should help:

```
 void StartThread(ThreadStart method) {
     new Thread(method).Start();
 }
```

and call it with:

```
 StartThread(myMethod);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a method or function as a delegate in .NET

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static void Iteration(Happy ending) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ending));
        t.Start();
    }

    public delegate void Happy();
```

inside your main:

```
Iteration(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
```